# How to check if a file is used by another process in C++?

Tags: c++, file, filesystems, fstream, data-race

I need to check if a file is currently opened by another process, e.g. a text editor (but needs to apply to everything else too).

I tried using `std::ofstream::is_open()` etc., but this did not work. I could open the file in my text editor while my program was checking if it was open. The program saw it as a closed file and went on. Only if I opened it as another `ofstream` would this work.

I'm using the filesystem library to copy files and they may only be copied (and later removed) if the file is not currently written to by another process on the client server.

Really curious about this one. Been wondering this for quite some time but never found a good way for it myself.

I'm currently making a program that needs to be able to run on both linux and windows. every 5 seconds it copies all files from directory a,b,c,d to x. This can be set by the client in rules. after it copied everything. all the files may be removed. After a day (or whatever the client tells the program) all those files from x need to be zipped and archived on location y. Hence the problem, files may only be deleted (and copied) if the other programs that place all the files in directories a,b,c,d are not touching that specific file right now. Hope that makes the question clearer.

And before anybody starts. Yes I know about the data race condition. I do not care about this for now. The program does absolutely nothing with the contents of a file. And after a file is closed by the other process, it will be closed forever.

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one about checking if another process has the file open. It's the one to which you believe the solution is to check whether another process has the file open.

Comment: Don't comment your own question. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26696274) it

Comment: On MS-Windows, I believe, a process that opens a file either ends up locking the file automatically, or explicitly do that, and prevent it from being deleted. On Linux, deleting a file does not affect, at all, any other process that's reading it. It will continue to read it normally, even if after it's deleted as far as any other process is concern. So, it looks like the problem you think existed, doesn't really exist, and nothing really needs to be done, for this.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to check if a file is currently opened by another process

### This is heavily operating system specific (and might be useless)

So read first a good [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/).

**On Linux** specifically you might use [inotify(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities, or `/proc/` pseudo-file system (see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)), or perhaps [lsof(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html). They work only for local file systems (not remote ones, like [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System)). See also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

And you could have surprises (e.g. a process being scheduled so quickly that removes a file that you won't have time to do anything)

**For Windows** take more time to read [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/).

> I'm currently making a program that needs to be able to run on both linux and windows. every 5 seconds it copies all files from directory a,b,c,d to x.

### You might look, at least for inspiration, inside the source code of [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/).

<sup>I don't understand what your actual problem is, but `rsync` might be part of the solution and is rumored to run on both Windows and Linux</sup>

Comment: It needs to run on a windows server and the client made a comment stating that "more and more customers are switching to linux" so it needs to be able to run on both. For the time being, I know that a file that's about 5 minutes old, are not touched any longer. So for now I will use time. But a way to check OS independitly if a file is in currently in use would be a great feature.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried upvoting it but i'm not yet allowed. Been a lurker on this forum for to long :)